# Merging bulk .newick files into a single newick file

Tags: r, bioinformatics, phylogeny, r-ape

I have approx 1000 newick files for different isolates of an organism. I would like to combine all these newick file and construct a tree for all the isolates for analysis.

I tried using tree.bind in Ape package of R but it does only take two parameters a time. Can someone suggest how binding of multiple trees can be achieved in R.

Thanks in advance!